# 'File' does not contain a definition for 'Delete'

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, delete-file

I'm just starting to learn ASP.NET. I'm using VWD 2010 Express and am trying to delete a file via delete button in a GridView.

Looking at examples on here and elsewhere, one method seems to be similar to this:

```
using System.IO;

public void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    string filePath = row.Cells[3].Text;
    File.Delete(filePath);        
}
```

Apologies if this is an idiotic noob question, but I'm stuck at the last line, with the error: 
`'File' does not contain a definition for 'Delete'`

I hope this is enough information for someone to point out where I'm going wrong but can post more code if needed.

-EDIT- Solution explorer image added for clarity:

[image]

Comment: Do you by any chance have your own class called `File`? Try `global::System.IO.File.Delete` just to remove any ambiguity, and let us know how you get on.

Comment: Maybe you get this error because you cannot delete a file from a webpage...

Comment: @Jon: I have a folder called `Files` but no class called `File`. Nonetheless, I tried using `global::System.IO.File.Delete` and it worked! Thank you very much indeed, sir. If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it. Also, any ideas what else might've caused it?

Comment: Unless you also have something "alternative" called `System`, it will be enough to say `System.IO.File`, i.e. you can skip `global::` in that case. Also, you could change your `using` declaration into an alias, if you need to use `System.IO.File` a lot and cannot get rid of the other `File` class. A using alias looks like `using sysFile = System.IO.File;` and with that you can just use `sysFile` with no extra qualification (provided that the name `sysFile` is not used for something else in an inner scope, of course).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, it seems that `File` means *something* other than `System.IO.File`. You can make it unambiguous this way:

```
global::System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
```

... but you should really work out what `File` means *without* that.

If you just write `File` and hover over it, you should be able to get a bit more information. Perhaps a property with that name?

Once you've found out where the problem is coming from, you could work out whether to rename it, or use the above way of making it completely unambiguous.

Comment: Typing File and hovering over, says it is a class so your first supsicion appears to have been correct after all. That said, I've no idea where this class is. The project itself is called `FileDB`. Could that be the issue? I've added an image of the solution explorer, in case that helps.

Comment: @Robert: Maybe try going to the declaration? Put your cursor within `File` and hit F12...

Comment: OK, that helped. Within DataClasses.designer is a partial class called File. Can I just rename it to `FilePartial` (or something) or am I as well leaving things as they are?

Comment: @Robert: I know nothing about DataClass.designer, I'm afraid. I would suggest you *use* the designer to look at these classes though.

Comment: OK, I've obviously a bit of studying to do. Thanks for all your help. It's appreciated.